# How to use database without installing it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have a database  in SQL Server 2008. I want to deploy my software with CD.
I want to give  end user 2 choices :Use from CD and install it.

When end user selects the "Use from CD", I don't want install program. 
How can I do program execution without installing?

Please help me about this problem

Thank you for your attention.
The program is coded In C# in MS visual studio 2010.Database Management system is MS Sql Server 2008

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "installing"? As in copy application to computer, or to avoid using the local hard drive alltogether?

Comment: Where should the database reside?

Comment: Database shoul reside in the cd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an embedded database which requires no setup and in-process execution, in your case best option is probably [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)

**Edit:** I know there are also other alternatives like BrekleyDb or SQLite but since Atayi is using SQL Server right now for his database, I suggested SQL Server Compact Edition to avoid any issue and stay on essentially the same technology/platform.

Comment: How you got any tutorial about this tecnique?

Comment: Hey Atayi, Google is your friend ;-) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/9cec5b3f-6f1e-4fa2-b1b1-9419e44f8247

Answer (score 5):

> Please help me about this problem

Don't use the technology you selected.

This is like saying "I want to drive a ferrari, but one that uses no fuel". Engines use fuel. SQL Server requires installation.

Alternative is SQL Server CE which you can load into the process.

THat is it. Run from CD is not possible without having SQL Server installed if you use SQL Server. Arguing wont change that.

Comment: i want to change it to MS SQL CE

Comment: May work. O not forget the other install requirement (.net Frameowrk). THat said, this is not a BIG problem these days, but still you will find a number of users not having it installed. LFew, though, since AMD uses it in their drivers, too, for video cards (their control center is written in .NET).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know if SQL Server '08 exists as a portable version, but if it burned on a cd, the use of a database is not there. The burned files cannot be changed :-)

A portable DBMS is SQLLite, there are bindings for C# :-)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server CE is a free, setup free, zero administration, embedded in process database engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can "Silent Install " Sql server also, that way the client will not be bothered by the configuration of the server.

Comment: yes but overkilling if you flood client's machine with a resident SQL Server engine instance only to browse a cd/catalog... imagine if every single CD you inserted in the reader would do this on your machine... :)

Answer (score 0):

When running from CD - change database back-end - use simple Microsoft Access Db file with ADO ODBC connection. In such case - you will have almost same SQL language and no need to install something for access db (huh, maybe general odbc drivers if they not exists).
When running from HD - switch db backend to full-scale MS SQL server ...

Comment: -1. These days that requires access to be installed which MAY NOT BE THE CASE. Drivers for access are not part of the main OS install anymore.